How can I retrieve the executable path for Google Chrome within a webpage?
I got this error when trying to run this code

Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://version/

<script type="text/javascript">
    window.open('chrome://version');
</script>


You can't. It's not information exposed by the web platform to your sandboxed JavaScript code.

At least localhost (http://127.0.0.1) should be allowed, right?

@nandin - There are security considerations even for code running against a local server. But there's also just no reason to bother providing such an API. APIs aren't free, they have to be developed and maintained.
